# Script to capture and send data to PC

Tags: shell-script

I need to write a script to automate the process of capturing and sending data.

I have the script **mqtt.py**(on my Raspberry Pi) which constantly captures and stores data in **myFile.dat**.
I use the **rsync** command to send the file from my **Raspberry Pi** to my **pc**.

I need to run the **mqtt.py** script to start capturing data and lets say after **1 minute**, the process stops and the file is sent to my pc and afterwards the capturing process is launched again and after 1 min same thing again.

I tried to write the script and i am missing the command to kill the process mqtt.py.

```
while(true) do

python mqtt.py #Capturing and storing data in myFile.dat
echo "Process mqtt.py started"

sleep 60 #After 1 minute

#Command to kill process mqtt.py

echo "Process mqtt.py stopped"

#Sending myFile.dat to PC
rsync -avz --remove-source-files myFile.dat chb-pc@192.168.100.7:/home/chb-pc/Desktop/ftp
echo "File sent to destination"

done
```

Comment: `pkill mqtt.py` should be enough.

Comment: For some reasons it did not work. I found another alternative to end the process after 60 seconds by adding some lines in my python program.

Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a time-based requirement, I would suggest using `timeout` as an alternative:

```
timeout 60 python mqtt.py
```

`timeout` will start the command (`python mqtt.py`) and wait for the specified duration (60 seconds in this case). If the command is still running after that, a signal will be sent to the command to terminate it. The default signal is SIGTERM, but you can specify an alternate signal. You can also send a secondary SIGKILL signal to ensure that the program is actually killed.

The manual for timeout can be found [here](https://ss64.com/bash/timeout.html).

Comment: @BhavishSDussoye That's great :-). If my answer has resolved your problem completely, you may mark it as accepted by clicking the 'tick' mark next to it. This grants reputation to both of us.